# proper way to dispatch an action in redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

my objective is to dispatch an action so that i can pass my state object.

```
import { addUser } from './actions' //action creator

this.state = {
  person: {
   name: '',
   age: 0,
  },
  isLoading: true,
}
```

//local func..

```
addNewUser = () => {
  //dispatches conditionally so the local func..
  this.props.addUser(this.state.person);
}
```

//dispatch

```
mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  addUser: (person) => dispatch(addUser(person)),
})
```

error is obviously on my mapDispatch(assinging the state in the wrong way). How could i solve it?(or is there any better way, but has to use action creators)
appreciate in advance.

Comment: The error *on my mapDispatch* isn't obvious to me. What is the result with this code now?

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to do. Could you please try to explain a little more what you are looking forward to do? what the error it's? what problem are you having? I'm on the same boat as @stone

Comment: The mapDispatchToProps looks ok to me. Have you created a reducer to handle the dispatched message and is it linked to your state object?

Comment: the problem is with i'm trying to send my local state obj as a parameter to my action creator.
1. in my local func, if i pass it as a parm is that the right way to receive in my mapdispatch....

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have your actions correct.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    addUser: (person) => {
      dispatch(addUser(person))
    },
  }
}
```

I believe you are missing only the return {} on your mapDispatchToProps

Comment: No, since he put the object in parens, it becomes the return value of the arrow function. No `return` needed.

Answer (score 0):

I find it's simpler to connect your actions to your export and call `this.props.addUser` as it by default assigns dispatch to it without needing to do `mapDispatchToProps`

```
export default connect(
    mapStateToProps, 
    {action1, action2, addUser})(User)
```

then you can still use:

```
addNewUser = () => {
  this.props.addUser(this.state.person);
}
```

and then do the rest within the action or reducer itself (depending on your preference of flow) such as:

```
export const addUser = user => ({
    type: ADD_USER_SUCCESS,
    payload: {user}
})
```

This is indeed more useful as performing logic out of components is more scalable and managable. If you have 10 actions it gets out of hand quickly, and you start mixing different types of logic.

Comment: thanks for the response. but as i stated as earlier, i need to dispatch it via mapDispatchToProps. I guess you understand my problem. so can you please convert it using mapDispatch format.

Comment: this.props.addUser(this.state.person);

addUser: (person) => dispatch(addUser(person))

are those two lines correct..?